# Netbeans. Php. Глубина видимости методов

Tags: php, классы, netbeans

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть класс подключения к базе данных:

```
 class DB {
      function __construct() {}
      public function GetOne(){}
     }
```

И есть класс user:

```
 include_once '../config/db.php';
 class user {
     private  $db;
     private function __construct() {
         $db = new DB();

     }
     public function CheckUser(){
         $this->db->GetOne();
     }
 }
```

NetBeans дает подсказку по коду при создании переменной **$db** как экземпляр класса DB, но не дает подсказку при вызове методов класса DB, т.е. он не подсказывает методы при состоянии строки *$this->db->|*.

Проблема кроется в том, что где-то в настойках NetBeans стоит ограничение на глубину вхождения, или же я как-то неправильно объявляю свойство класса ($db) ?

Comment: 99% что необходимо подсказать нетбинсу тип с помощью PHPDoc

    /*
     * @var DB
     */
    private $db;

Правильней будет указывать `@type`, но я не уверен, что его уже поддерживает нетбинс.  
При таких подсказках везде глубина нахождения методов должна быть неограниченной.

Comment: @Etki, добавил, не помогло. Похожу в тот 1% попал)

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая, я звездочку забыл, без нее это не PHPDoc

    /**
     * @var DB
     */
    private $db;

в 7.4 все отлично схватилось. Кстати, в меню автодополнения при вводе `$this->db` уже можно увидеть, как NB трактует эту переменную: слева стоит либо знак вопроса, либо конкретный класс.